# IIS7-PHP how to increase the time before timeout error?

Tags: php, sql, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Good day.

We have IIS7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

When we use php script in server we get error:

```
Error in query mainres enterres preparation/execution. 

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 
            [1] => 258 [code] => 258 
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
            ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 
            [1] => 258 [code] => 258 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure 
            ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
            [0] => 08S01 [SQLSTATE] => 08S01 
            [1] => -2147467259 [code] => -2147467259 
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure 
            ) 
    )
```

As we can see `Shared Memory Provider: Timeout error`

*Tell me please how to increase the time before timeout error ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**php.ini:**

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300
default_socket_timeout = 300
```

**MSSQL Server:**

```
mssql.connect_timeout = 300
mssql.timeout = 300
```

**IIS7:**

[image]

P.S.: *config php.ini also you can change in manager iis7*

Answer (score 1):

This error may be related to the setting in your `php.ini` configuration file.

Search for the following items and change (INCREASE) their values, for example:

```
max_execution_time = 600  
max_input_time = 600
default_socket_timeout = 60
```

And, if you use MSSQL Server:

```
mssql.connect_timeout = 60
mssql.timeout = 60
```

If you use MySQL server:

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
```

Comment: it not work. i have timeout after 2 minutes... where can be problem?